# Testing tanstack-react-qiery - (wait for is not a function in renderHook)

Tags: react-testing-library, react-query

> **I want to test this customHook but it's showing me an error of
> waitFor is not a function.**

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useCustomHookForTestCase } from "../useQueryCustomHook";
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

// jest.mock('../../../Utilies/Apicall')

describe('Testing custom hooks of react query', () => {
    const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            {children}
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );

    it('Should get data of todos from api',async () => {
        const { result, waitFor } = await renderHook(() => useCustomHookForTestCase(), { wrapper });

        await waitFor(() => result.current.isSuccess );

        expect(result.current.data).toEqual("Hello");
    })
})

export function useCustomHookForTestCase() {
  return useQuery(['customHook'], () => 'Hello');
}
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only `renderHook` from [react-hook-testing-library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#renderhook) returns a `waitFor` method. It is not available if you use the one from `@testing-library/react-hooks`. For that to work, you just need to import `waitFor` directly. You also can't return a boolean directly, but it needs to be a promise:

```
import { renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'

await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isSuccess).toBe(true))
```